# IOS: How to detect timezone changed by user in background fetch

Tags: ios, timezone, background-fetch

Is there any way to detect when user change the phone timezone, or when it changes automatically at background fetch?! 
I need to reschedule all my local notifications when the phone timezone changes.

Comment: As a third party dev, I don't that we are able to do it...

Comment: Could you add code which create a local notification. I think that UNCalendarNotificationTrigger should be time zone independent. So, if you schedule it at for example 9:00 at some date it will fire at local user time even if he change time zone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you

```
optional func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange